# Vue component is routing me to another component

Tags: vue.js, routes

I just started in VUE and im having when trying to go to components. I currently have 2 components: List and Detail. The List one loads perfectly but the Detail does not and im blinded by hours of staring at the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
**main.js**

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import List from './components/List.vue';
import Detail from './components/Detail.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
    const routes = [{
      path: '/list',
      name: 'List',
      component: List
    },
    {
      path: '/detail',
      name: 'Detail',
      component: Detail
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      component: List
    }]




**Detail.Vue**

        <template>
    <div>
       <h1>The Detail</h1>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        name: "Detail"
    };
    </script>
    <style>
    
    </style>
```

Comment: This looks ok (assuming the app is mounted somewhere not shown in *main.js*).  Can you show where you're trying to change routes?

Comment: I forgot to add information as usual..

Im at localhost:8080 watching this. But when im trying to access localhost:8080/detail is does not load.

When trying to enter localhost:8080/list the list component DOES load, how ever the Detail one does not.

Comment: Is the issue only when typing the url?  Does it work if you use a `router-link` to change routes?  If so this is a server configuration issue

Comment: For now i have not done any Router-links at all. I'm fresh in Vue and after hours of looking at this code compairing to code that works i just can't find the problem to where it goes wrong.